# How to finish the bot-authentication dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, botframework, chatbot, sample

I am working with the bot-auth sample and after having the user logged in I need to be able to interact with the user, in my case I would like to start with an echo. I can't find a way to end the dialog and for the bot to start answering the user. Could you guide me with an example or ideas? Thanks

I wouldn't need to show the token, so at this point it would be enough for me to finish here and start interacting with the user

**main_dialog.py**

```py
async def login_step(self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext) -> DialogTurnResult:
    # Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
    # token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
    if step_context.result:
        await step_context.context.send_activity("You are now logged in.")
        return await step_context.prompt(
            ConfirmPrompt.__name__,
            PromptOptions(
                prompt=MessageFactory.text("Would you like to view your token?")
            ),
        )

    await step_context.context.send_activity(
        "Login was not successful please try again."
    )
    return await step_context.end_dialog()
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Please guide me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources and recommendations is *specifically* listed as off topic.  Asking for a block of code is *specifically* listed as off topic.

Comment: @Im_ml - Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please link to the sample you're using? It looks like the code you posted already shows you how to do what you say you're trying to do. With that code, the bot will immediately start interacting with the user by asking the user a question once the user is signed in. What is it that you're trying to do that's different from that? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thank you for welcoming me to this beautiful community. I could achieve my goal, which was once finished the login of the user to start, e.g, using a echo_bot or qna_bot. The problem is that I couldn't get out of the login-show token dialog loop. The solution "I found" is to create a `user_state.create_property()` in **main_dialog.py** and access properties defined `get(turn_context)` in **dialog_bot.py**. With this I was able to leave the dialogue. Thanks for your time! Have a nice day!

Comment: @Im_ml - Would you like to post that as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve my goal, which was once finished the login of the user to start, e.g, using a **echo_bot** or **qna_bot**. The problem is that I couldn't get out of the login-show token dialog loop. The solution "I found" is to create a `user_state.create_property()` in **main_dialog.py** and access properties defined `get(turn_context)` in **dialog_bot.py**. With this I was able to leave the dialogue.